# If one column is above 35 need to change a different column to 1 or 0 based on previous column output. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have one column I need to loop through to see if it is greater than 35, if it is greater than 35(the number in the row) I need to set another column to 1 per row.

```
for i in df["column_name"]:
   if i > 35:
      df["another_column"] = 1
   else:
      df["another_column"] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df["another_column"] = df["column_name"].gt(35).astype(bool)
```